# Java: are nested classes the solution to this issue?

Tags: java, class, nested

I have a Java class with two constructors. There are a lot of methods within this class. Most of those methods will behave correctly regardless of which constructor is used, but a few will need to behave differently. Let's say methodA() is the latter, I could just recreate it and use two methods with different names, but that would mean refactoring a lot of code in the rest of the application and generally seems like a bad solution. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
public class Example {

     public Example(int x, int y) {}
     public Example(int x){}

     public methodA(){
          //If the first constructor is called, this method needs to behave 
          //differently than if the second were called.
     }

     public methodB(){
          //But I still want access to this method, which behaves the same regardless
     }
```

My thought is to use nested classes, created two nested classes with different methodA()'s but having the same methodB() in the parent class. Is there a better way to implement what I desire or am I on the right track?

Many thanks.

Comment: It is strange that a method behaves differently because of the constructor called. Maybe what you need is a subclass that reimplements such a method.

Comment: Inheritance is the best way to override and implement what you need.

Comment: It is not clear exactly in which way it "behaves differently". In some cases that would possibly make sense, depending on what you mean. Do you really need to bother yourself with nested classes? Isn't it enough to look at the state of the instance and execute the proper logic?

Comment: You should think about [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186921) for [the four questions you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2341412/user2341412?tab=questions) (of course, only if there's one that solved your problem).

Answer (score 2):

A classic inheritance should suit your needs:

```
public class SuperExample {

    public SuperExample(int x) {
    }

    public void methodA() {
    }

    public void methodB() {
    }

}

public class SubExample extends SuperExample {

    public SubExample(int x, int y) {
        super(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void methodA() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to apply polymorphism here. Create a parent class with all the common methods and subclass that one to create the different behavior. Instantiation could happen via a factory (maybe look up factory pattern if you're not sure) depending on the parameters.